# Как заставить intellig idea community edition смотреть application.properties для Spring Boot JPA?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, boot, spring-jpa

Подключил через Maven Spring Boot, JPA. Создал необходмые классы, сущности и контроллер. Без подключения БД Spring Boot работает отлично, но , когда пытаюсь подключить к проекту данные из БД не понимаю как заставить IDEA принимать настройки из application.properties. Дело в том, что настройки светятся как серые , типо не используются. Почитал, что в Community Edition нельзя через application.properties прописать настройки. Может кто подскажет альтернативные способы? А то обидно, Spring Boot работает, а с БД работать не могу.

Вот application.properties на всякий, но я точно знаю, что Spring его не видит ( пробовал всякую чепуху писать- работает одинаково плохо) и это не проблема в самих настройках.

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./SalesPointscds
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Вот скриншоты

**Controller:**

```
    package RestExample.MainPack.Controller;

import RestExample.MainPack.model.SALESPOINTDO;
import RestExample.MainPack.repos.SalesPointRepos;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    SalesPointRepos salesPointRepos;


    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    @ResponseBody
    public String greeting() {


        Iterable<SALESPOINTDO> allSP=salesPointRepos.findAll();

        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

        allSP.forEach(sp->sb.append(sp+"<br>"));


        return  sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Entity:**

```
    package RestExample.MainPack.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "SALESPOINTDO")
public class SALESPOINTDO {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int ID;

 @Column(name = "NAME")
 private String name;

 @Column(name = "CITY")
 private String city;

 @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
 private String address;

    public SALESPOINTDO() {
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "City: "+getCity()+" "+"Address: "+getAddress();
    }
}
```

**SpringBootApp:**

```
package RestExample.MainPack;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StartRest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartRest.class,args);
    }
}
```

**POM xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.home</groupId>
    <artifactId>REST</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

репозиторий

```
package RestExample.MainPack.repos;

import RestExample.MainPack.model.SALESPOINTDO;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


public interface SalesPointRepos extends CrudRepository<SALESPOINTDO,Long> {

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Развернутый вариант :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103839/discussion-on-question-by-vaagn-akopyan---intellig-idea-community-ed).

Answer (score 0):

Не указывайте версии библиотек в пом, они возьмутся и парента. 
Поднимите версию Spring-boot до `2.2.4.RELEASE`. 
В свойствах укажите версию java

```
 <properties> 
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>
```